# How can I test if a set is linearly independent?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

Is there a function that takes a list like

`{{1,0,3},{0,-3,1}}`

and decide if the vectors `(1,0,3)` and `(0,-3,1)` are linearly independent or not?

It would be great if the output is 1 for **yes** (they are linearly independent) and 0 for **no** (they are linearly dependent). I aim to select from a list of lists those whose vectors are linearly independent. Maybe I can use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to do it because if the output is 0 or 1 I can put the result as a criteria in the argument of `Select`. For example, Let

`S={{{1,0,13},{2,12,1}},{{1,13,0},{2,26,0}},{{1,-4,2},{-2,8,-4}},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0}}}`

I want to obtain from `S` the subset

`B={{{1,0,13},{2,12,1}},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0}}}`

of its linearly independent lists.

Another way to do that could be by calculating the minors, but I think this would complicate things.

Comment: You've seen `NullSpace[]`, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to find the [`MatrixRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank) of the list:

```
S = {
    {{1,0,13},{2,12,1}},
    {{1,13,0},{2,26,0}},
    {{1,-4,2},{-2,8,-4}},
    {{1,0,0},{0,1,0}}
};

MatrixRank[#] == 2& /@ S
```

> {True, False, False, True}

Then, you can use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick) to obtain what you want:

```
Pick[S, MatrixRank[#] == 2& /@ S]
```

> {{{1, 0, 13}, {2, 12, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}

Comment: Why would you want to use `Pick[S, MatrixRank[#] == 2& /@ S]` over `Select[S, MatrixRank[#] == 2&]`?